# Infragistics UltraGrid (9.2) change a cell displayvalue without changing underlying datasource

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a UltraGrid bound to a `IList<MyDomainObject>`. In MyDomainObject there is a field `bool? isSomething`. Problem is when this field is null the check-box in the cell is displayed as sort of a filled check-box, not as an unchecked check-box as my customer wants it. So in a `InitializeRow`-eventhandler I change the value of the cell in question to false if its value is null. But this also changes the underlying data in the MyDomainObject-object - which is not desirable.

How can I change the display-value of my field `bool? isSomething` without changing the value in the domain-object?

Comment: Whats the value of your checkbox column style property?

Comment: This is a similar discussion which might help you: http://news.infragistics.com/forums/p/1607/12828.aspx

Comment: Thanks Vija, your "column style question" got me to a solution, but I'm not allowed to post it to my own Q in yet a few hours.

Comment: Glad to know that you have got the solution @AndreasExchange, I think you should be able to post your answer for complete understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Vijay.
The style property of the column was set to Default. This produces a three-value checkbox style. By setting the style to a two-value checkbox null is displayed as false.

```
private readonly List<string> _nullableBoolColumns;

private void OnInitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var band in e.Layout.Bands)
    {
        foreach (var column in band.Columns)
        {                    
            if(column.DataType == typeof(bool?))
            {
                 _nullableBoolColumns.Add(column.Key);
            }                    
        }
    }
}

private void OnInitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string column in _nullableBoolColumns)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[column].Style = ColumnStyle.CheckBox;
    }
}
```